# Построение вложенных комментариев

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет, есть вопрос по построению вложенных комментариев. Каким образом лучше это реализовать? С бэка приходит такой JSON:

```
   [
     {
      "commentText": "Это родитель",
      "pageID": 1,
      "userID": 1,
      "date": "2021-12-25 14:00:00",
      "path": "000000001",
      "dateModified": "2021-12-25 14:00:00",
      "isDelete": "False",
      "isPrivate": "False",
      "attachment": []
    },
    {
      "commentText": "Это первый потомок",
      "pageID": 1,
      "userID": 2,
      "date": "2021-12-25 14:10:00",
      "path": "000000001000000002",
      "dateModified": "2021-12-25 14:10:00",
      "isDelete": "False",
      "isPrivate": "False",
      "attachment": []
    },
    {
      "commentText": "Это второй потомок",
      "pageID": 1,
      "userID": 3,
      "date": "2021-12-25 14:15:00",
      "path": "000000001000000003",
      "dateModified": "2021-12-25 14:15:00",
      "isDelete": "False",
      "isPrivate": "False",
      "attachment": []
    },
    {
      "commentText": "Это третий потомок",
      "pageID": 1,
      "userID": 4,
      "date": "2021-12-25 14:20:00",
      "path": "000000001000000002000000003",
      "dateModified": "2021-12-25 14:20:00",
      "isDelete": "False",
      "isPrivate": "False",
      "attachment": []
    },
    {
      "commentText": "Это четвертый потомок",
      "pageID": 1,
      "userID": 1,
      "date": "2021-12-25 14:12:00",
      "path": "000000001000000003000000004",
      "dateModified": "2021-12-25 14:12:00",
      "isDelete": "False",
      "isPrivate": "False",
      "attachment": []
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Дайте пример выходных данных, которые хотите иметь по итогу

Comment: Я так понимаю, что в каждом объекте создается массив children в который складываются его потомки, если они есть, а затем в template отрисовываются через цикл v-for

Comment: У потомка может быть еще потомок или нет?

Comment: Да, может. Вообщем принцип такой: есть родитель id:17 path: 000000017, его 1 потомок будет id:18 path: 000000017000000018, соответственно ответ на 1-го потомка будет id:19 path: 000000017000000018000000019. Максимальная вложенность 5